# How to Query multiple tables dynamically VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have 30 different tables in my database in every tables has same column name `"res_ret"=define as` 0 in **every tables**. I want to Update and Set `res_ret value=1` . This is my code and this is work. How can I do this in dynamic codings. Thanks in Advance :)

```
conn.Open()

sql = "Update table_1 SET res_ret= 1"
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

sql = "Update table_2 SET res_ret=1"
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

sql = "Update table_3 SET res_ret=1"
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Dispose()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: If you have so many similar tables it is a strong indication of a poor  database design. Maybe you should instead use one table with a new column `TypeID`.

Comment: Thanks man for the response :) yahh but I need to do this dynamically .

Comment: Although I agree with @TimSchmelter, I realize that sometimes you can get thrown into situations where you're maintaining an existing poor database structure, and can't do much about it (i.e. because some prepackaged solution relies on the lousy design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally This Codes Work ..
Dim tableList = {"table_1", "table_2", "table_3"}

```
        For Each tableName As String In tableList
            conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("update {0} set res_ret = 1", tableName)
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        Next
```

Answer (score 1):

As @TimSchmelter points out, there is probably a better way of doing this, but:

VB.NET

```
Dim tableList = { "table_1", "table_2", "table_3" }

For Each tableName As String In tableList
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("update {0} set res_ret = 1", tableName)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

c#

```
var tableList = new List<string> { "table_1", "table_2", "table_3" ... };

foreach(var tableName in tableList) {
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("update {0} set res_ret = 1", tableName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: In your VB.Net code, you're missing a `=` or `As`, like `Dim tableList = New List...`. Or, simply use `Dim tableList = { "table_1", "table_2", "table_3" }`, since you don't need a `List` anyway.

Comment: man many thanks but i have an error: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Comment: Can I ask some question? Do I need to Insert all my tables in tableList in order?

Comment: sloth and paul dude I have an error in this code .. the error is PROCEDURE db_name.table1 does not exist . What do you think ?

Comment: thanks Paul the only error is I put the connection.open above the for each loop . By the way thank you and God Bless .. ^_^v